# How to use the Noto Sans Old Hungarian font?

Tags: fonts, hungarian

Noob here.

[Noto Sans Old Hungarian Font](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Old+Hungarian)

I downloaded and installed this font. I was expecting if I press an `a` I get the equalient letter from this alphabet.

[image]

But it doesn't do anything.

How to use this font?

Comment: Did you try with charmap to see where are these symbols (in which charset)?

Answer (score 1):

Noto fonts are not "alternative" fonts for Latin (ASCII) characters – instead, each font handles its own specific Unicode area, in this case the [Old Hungarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Hungarian_(Unicode_block)) Unicode block. (Unicode considers it a separate script, much like Greek or Cyrillic, which means the OS can automatically choose the appropriate font for each character without messing things up.)

Generally you need a separate [keyboard layout](https://github.com/staceybellerose/kbd-rovas) for each script. Alternatively, LibreOffice 7.0 supports [transliteration](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/7.0#Transliteration_to_Old_Hungarian).

You won't see this Unicode block in Windows Character Map because it starts at U+10C80, well outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, whereas Charmap is still limited to only the BMP.